# Why this is showing me nothing in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Why this is show me nothing??
I'm totally lost =(

```
<?php function calc_shortcode(){ ?>
<div>
    <form>
        <h3>Price High</h3>
        <input name="priceHigh" type="text" />
        <h3>Price Low</h3>
        <input name="priceLow" type="text" />
        <h3>Price Up</h3>
        <input name="priceUp" type="text" />
        <h3>Price Down</h3>
        <input name="priceDown" type="text" /></br>
        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Calculate" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </form>
</div>
<?php 
} 

add_shortcode('calc_pat', 'calc_shortcode');
```

Thanks for helping guys!

Comment: Wraping html with php wont output unless you tell.

Answer (score 1):

To use shortcode you need to call it. Read more here https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_shortcode/ and https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/

```
echo do_shortcode('[calc_pat]');
```

Answer (score 0):

The php labels are wrongly placed there, try doing this:

```
<?php
function calc_shortcode(){ 
<div>
    <form>
        <h3>Price High</h3>
        <input name="priceHigh" type="text" />
        <h3>Price Low</h3>
        <input name="priceLow" type="text" />
        <h3>Price Up</h3>
        <input name="priceUp" type="text" />
        <h3>Price Down</h3>
        <input name="priceDown" type="text" /></br>
        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Calculate" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </form>
</div>
 
} 

add_shortcode('calc_pat', 'calc_shortcode');
?>
```

Check if that works

Comment: that's not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please give try to below code, it should work:

```
function calc_shortcode(){ 
echo '<div>
    <form>
        <h3>Price High</h3>
        <input name="priceHigh" type="text" />
        <h3>Price Low</h3>
        <input name="priceLow" type="text" />
        <h3>Price Up</h3>
        <input name="priceUp" type="text" />
        <h3>Price Down</h3>
        <input name="priceDown" type="text" /></br>
        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Calculate" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </form>
</div>';
} 

add_shortcode('calc_pat', 'calc_shortcode');
```

you can also add ob_start(); and ob_get_clean();

Answer (score 0):

Try below code :

```
<?php function calc_shortcode()
{
    ob_start();
?>
    <div>
        <form>
            <h3>Price High</h3>
            <input name="priceHigh" type="text" />
            <h3>Price Low</h3>
            <input name="priceLow" type="text" />
            <h3>Price Up</h3>
            <input name="priceUp" type="text" />
            <h3>Price Down</h3>
            <input name="priceDown" type="text" /></br>
            <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Calculate" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </form>
    </div>
<?php
    echo ob_get_clean();
    die();
}

add_shortcode('calc_pat', 'calc_shortcode');
```